# make ajax call in material design using Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, material-design

Here am using material design lite to build the project following that i have done my code like this but no result is showing on the corresponding field.
Here is my code,please have a look

```
<script>
$('#type').change(function(){
  var type=$('#type').val();
  alert(type);
  var url='<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/vehicle/ajax_vehicle';
  alert(url);
  $.post(url, {type:type}, function(data)
  {  
    alert(); 
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();      
    $('#vehicle').html(data);
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is my Controller

```
public function ajax_vehicle()
{
    $data['vehicle']=$this->Vehicle_model->view_available_vehicles($_POST['type']);
    //var_dump($data['vehicle']);
    $this->load->view('admin/vehicle/ajax_vehicle',$data);
}
```

Here is my View page

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
      <select  required name="vehicle_id" id="vehicle">
       <option value=""  selected>Select</option>


      </select>
      <label>Select Vehicle</label>
</div>
```

The `var type=$('#type').val();` is getting the value.
When i console it i got the result like this

```
 <select  required name="vehicle_id">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="42" >bullet</option>
   <option value="41" >pulsar</option>
</select>
```

This is my ajax_vehicle,need to display content of this after selecting the type choosed.

```
<select  required name="vehicle_id">
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <?php  if(empty($assign_vehicle_info)){
        if (!empty($vehicle)) {
        foreach ($vehicle as $veh) {?>
 <option value="<?= $veh->id ?>"<?php if (!empty($assign_vehicle_info)) { echo $assign_vehicle_info->vehicle_id == $veh->id ? 'selected' : ''; } ?>><?= $veh->name ?></option>
 <?php }}}?>
 </select>
```

actually don't know  what additional things to be added to this to work.pleae help me to solve

Comment: what debugging have you done? Does the ajax call succeed? Does it return a value within `data`? You need to do some basic debugging. You've basically effectively said "it doesn't work" and provided no specific error information. It could be failing in a number of places, but without specific error info we can only guess - there are enough unknowns to create several possibilities.

Comment: Does `base_url()` append a `/` on the end? If not, add one!

Comment: Is your ajax request working? You can confirm that by using the network panel of your web browser.

Comment: @ADyson when i console it and am getting correct value but that output is not showing on the page

Comment: @srimaln91 yaa my ajax request working properly

Answer (score 0):

if `data` contains

```
<select  required name="vehicle_id">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="42" >bullet</option>
   <option value="41" >pulsar</option>
</select>
```

as you state, then the result of `$('#vehicle').html(data);` will be

```
<select  required name="vehicle_id" id="vehicle">
  <select  required name="vehicle_id">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="42" >bullet</option>
   <option value="41" >pulsar</option>
  </select>
</select>
```

which as you can see is nonsensical and invalid HTML.  the `html()` function replaces the *inner* HTML of the selected element, not the element itself.

You have two options:

1) Change the server output (i.e the `ajax_vehicle` view) so it just returns the `<option>` elements - no need to return the outer part of the `<select>` as well. Therefore the resulting `data` returned from the ajax call would need to contain only (for example):

```
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="42" >bullet</option>
<option value="41" >pulsar</option>
```

Then you can continue to use `$('#vehicle').html(data);` as before.

OR

2) Use `replaceWith`, i.e. `$("#vehicle").replaceWith(data);` instead of `.html()`. But in this case you still need to amend your server output so that the `<select>` includes the `id="vehicle"` markup, otherwise this code will not work a second time, since an element called "vehicle" would no longer exist. Also bear in mind that if you have any event handlers etc set on the "vehicle" element, they would also need to be re-created, since you've replaced the whole element. See http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

In my opinion option 1 is the better choice.

Comment: i had tested both the cases but unfortunately no getting any thing

Comment: when i done with your second concept i just removed the <select> tag and the data came but not with in the <select>tag

Comment: "no getting anything" is not an error message or problem description. Please look at your page and be specific. You can check in your browser's developer tools what the "vehicle" element looks like after you've run the code. After you use my first option, what does it contain? It should contain just the new options.

Comment: "when i done with your second concept i removed the <select> tag and the data came but not with in the <select>tag". Don't really know what this means. The data "came out" where? You mean `data` was incorrect, or the resulting change replacement of the `<select>` was incorrect? Please be precise and give a clear example of what the end result was. Also confirm what the changed version of `data` looked like. I can't help you with just vague descriptions of your situation - this is a problem of detail, so we need detailed information in order to solve it.

Comment: i had changed the `$("#vehicle").html(data);` with `$("#vehicle").replaceWith(data);` and removed `select` tag from the view and starts with <option> at that time output came on the page.

Comment: The options I outlined were to remove the `<select>` from the returned `data` **OR** change to using `replaceWith`. One or the other, **not** both. It sounds like you have done both. Sorry if it was not clear that these were different alternatives.